# Wait for return value NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server which makes a call to an external module. My problem is that I need the data return by the call to the module but node (which is non-blocking) simply isn't waiting for the return value. Any solution to this ?

Code :

**Server.js**

```
var value = module.functionA(param);
console.log("Message one %s", value);
```

**Module.js**

```
function callToFunctionInModule(param){
console.log("In func");
return param+2;
}

exports.functionA = function(param){
console.log("Message two");
var returnVal = callToFunctionInModule(param);
return returnVal;
};
```

**Ouput**

```
Message two
Message one undefined
In func
```

Is there anyway to get the following output (waiting to get the return value from the module WITHOUT using callback in the line *var value = module.functionA(param);*

Comment: strange! according to me, it should work normally....

Comment: That's what I though too.. I don't know if it has to do with the call within the module it self...

Comment: Just checking...but is `param` assigned to anything before the initial call to `module.functionA`?

Comment: Well, in my program, param has something assigned to it. So instead of having "undef", the result is that it print Message one (original value) without the new value given back by the module

Comment: even if it is, still the output beats the common sense, since "in func" comes *after* "message 1 undefined"

Comment: Dunno if it would help, but in the "callToFunctionInModule", I make a mongoDB query... Still this output makes no sens what so ever to me

Comment: Is this the actual code or a generalized rendition? If it's generalized and `functionA` uses an asynchronous API, then no it can't wait.

Comment: Id have to check to see if the DB module is asyc (But I think it is). Assuming this, is there any way to make the code wait for the return value?

Comment: My main problem is that I make a query to the db then depending on the ouput I make an insertion to the Db..But I have to see result of the original query first..

Comment: I think the code given is perfectly sensible, i checked it up, but the output you gave is not perfectly sensible. I got the sensible, the perfectly, fully, absolutely, utterly sensible o/p:

Message two
In func
Message one 22

Comment: Could you try and make a callback function that will print your message AFTER the function returns?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, the code you gave (sync) doesn't represent the actual situation (async). What you should do in the case you want to deal with async stuff is use callbacks. That's the whole idea behind node.js - event-driven*ness*.

**Server.js**

```
module.functionA(param, function(val) {
    console.log("Message one %s", val);
});
```

**Module.js**

```
function callToFunctionInModule(param, cb) {
    console.log("In func");
    /* some db query */
    not_so_magical_async_stuff("blah", function(/* value passed as argument */) {
        cb(param + 2 /* or the value passed as an argument to this function */);
    }
}

exports.functionA = function (param, cb) {
    console.log("Message two");
    callToFunctionInModule(param, cb);
};
```

Now, what happens is this:
Function passed to `functionA` is passed on to `callToFunctionInModule`, which calls it back with the returned value as an argument. The result: non-blocking beautiful code! Trust me, once you get hooked into this async thingy, you'll love it!